# Use another set of resources in Android (NOT runtime, but compiletime)

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to build two different APK's from my Android application. The differance between the two are  images in the res/drawable directory. I know that it is possible to use a different set of resources during runtime depending on language settings, hardware or other, but how to do it compiletime? (is it possible to specify another directory then res/drawable?)

(currently, i'm copying/replacing all resources each time i want to build a new version)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sound like you need to use Ant build tools.

Create in your project a custom folder that contains to different assets folders for each APK,
then, use ANT build with a proper configuration file that u need to create to build the project with the appropriate assets and files before it's beening compiled.

Good luck!

Update:

Here is a tutorial for using the Ant build tool with android:
[Android Ant build tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidBuildAnt/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should use the assets? I find a link that talks about the resources and assets!: [here](http://www.wiseandroid.com/post/2010/06/14/Android-Beginners-Intro-to-Resources-and-Assets.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility could be to use 2 different library project and put in these project your images / values. you would have to change the properties of the project each time you need to compile with another library project

It's a bit inconvenient but would work...

Hope it helps